# Список языков для веб-сайта

Tags: php, javascript

У меня в разработке веб-сайт, основаный на переводах слов с разных языков в другие. Проблема что это будет по сути максимально открытый словарь, то есть ввести слово можно будет на любом языке и потому нужен полный список всех существующих языков в мире.

Проблема в том что их более 100 и мне нужна библиотека названий. То есть полное название, короткое название и название написанное тем же языком. Нет ли каких-либо открытых API или готовых списков что бы это можно было реализовать и как это вообще называется? Или правильней будет создать свой список? Ну и если создавать свой то как лучше: создать массив в самом PHP/JS или выделить таблицу бд для этого?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал для таких вещей делать всё лучше в БД

Comment: Я бы скопировал что-нибудь такое из википедии и запихнул в бд

Comment: Вот тут: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes есть таблица языков, нужно лишь спарсить нужные данные

Comment: @XYZ Спасибо, подойдет :)